# why i should add dependencies that in aar file to my project?

Tags: android, gradle, dependencies, android-gradle-plugin, aar

I created the my Android Archive Library `aar` file that have it's own dependency in it's Gradle.
I use this library in many projects of mine, but why I should add `aar` dependency to my application dependencies? as we know benefit of using aar vs jar is aar can have and hold it's own resources and dependencies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The **aar** file **doesn't contain the nested (or [transitive](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html#Transitive_Dependencies)) dependencies** and doesn't have a pom file which describes the dependencies used by the library.

It means that, if you are importing a aar file using a `flatDir` repo you have to specify the dependencies also in your project.

You should use a **maven repository** (you have to publish the library in a private or public maven repo), you will not have the same issue.
In this case, gradle downloads the dependencies using the pom file which will contains the dependencies list.

Comment: thanks. so tell me how I can change my arr to maven repository mode, so I can test your answer?

Comment: It depends if the repo can be public (as centralmaven or jcenter) or private. In the second case you have to use an own maven repo.